# Heroku | No such app There is no app configured at that hostname (changed domain to a new one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dns

I bought a new custom domain and decided to use it for my existing heroku app.

It was http://www.xyz.com and I changed it to http://www.abc.com

I removed xyz.com and www.xyz.com from my heroku app using the console

Then I added abc.com and www.abc.com, and these are working just fine.

I went to my godaddy DNS panel and pointed the former domain xyz.com (host www) to boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com. I also put a forward on xyz.com to www.abc.com.

After about 2 hours, when I try to go to the former domain www.xyz.com, I get the no such app error. Xyz.com (without the www) appears to work because it's forwarded.

Did I miss a step on getting www.xyz.com to work though? Where do the "A Hosts" for www.xyz.com need to be pointed to?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - did you resolve this, if so how?

Answer (score 3):

In your DNS panel, `www.xyz.com` should be a `CNAME` to `boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com`.

In short, apex domains should forward to a subdomain (www), then that sub domain should be a CNAME to your *.herokuapp.com.